# Is there an official symbol for repetition in a table

Tags: punctuation, editing

In one of the tables of a paper, I used a hyphen to indicate the repetition of the value in a cell into the one below.
Here is an (ugly) example:

```
╭────────╥────────────┬─────────────────────╮
│        ║     id     │       species       │
╞════════╬════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ crab   ║ C#01       │ Cancer borealis     │
│        ║ C#02       │ -                   │
│        ║ C#03       │ -                   │
│        ║            │                     │
│ shrimp ║ S#01       │ Lysmata amboinensis │
│        ║ S#02       │ Stenopus hispidus   │
│        ║ S#03       │ Lysmata amboinensis │
└────────╨────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Here, hyphens mean that C#02 and C#03 are of the same species as C#01 (*Cancer borealis*)

Unfortunately, the editor refused this formatting because in tables hyphens usually stand for missing values.

So my question is: would there be a more appropriate, standard symbol for vertical repetition in a table?

Comment: The normal symbol is "ditto marks" - which, for most modern computing/typing purposes are identical to 'double quote' marks: *"*.  Personally, I would use either the **word** "*ditto*" or "*as above*".  I would agree with your editor that the hyphens/dashes are inappropriate and usually mean "no value".

Comment: This is not a question about the English language. This belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the English language but about symbols used in mathematics or computing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *[ditto mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditto_mark)*, (also known as *double quotation marks*) would seem appropriate

> The ditto mark (〃)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditto_mark) is a typographic symbol indicating that the word(s) or figure(s) above it are to be repeated.

*Wikipedia*

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that, apart from the "Ditto" and ditto mark ("), "Do" is also used to signify that the value of a particular field is same as that of the preceding field.

"Do" perhaps refers to abbreviated form of "Ditto".